# JQUERY: ID not found, just defined before

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem I don't understand.
I want to create a datepicker with JQUERY (UI-1.9.1 + JQ 1.8.2)

I define the

`<input id="date1" .... value="">
<a href="javascript:$('#date1').focus();">DateSelClickHere</a>`

*"DateSelClickHere"* should be a picture later on.

If you now click to the empty datefield, it just works fine.
If you click to the text (or image),I get this: **[object Object]**

Sample here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3DH3L/

I don't get it?!?

PS: I will try it with the property "image" - but - this is the crap - it's not my code and I just start with this project, so I first search for the "easy way" to fix the errors.

Comment: Works well on my Chrome! :)

Comment: Works fine on chrome for me too

Comment: The only error i get after selecting a date is "Uncaught ReferenceError: changeDate is not defined"

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 30,0 ...
->  "Uncaught ReferenceError: changeDate is not defined"
It's not the full code at all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a JavaScript URIs. The purpose of these is to generate a document to display by running some JavaScript.

If you just want to run some JS, then use a button. Use a link only if you want to link somewhere.

```
<input type="button" value="DateSelKlickHere">
```

You *could* use an onclick attribute, but you'd be better off binding your JS with JavaScript.

```
$('#date1 + input[type="button"]').on("click", function (evt) {
    $('#date1').focus();
});
```